# Separable prefix position in questions

Tags: word-order

"Was würden Sie mit auf die Reise nehmen?" I found this sentence on VHS website. But reverse translating gives me, "Was würden Sie auf die Reise mitnehmen?" The position of "mit" in the second sentence seems the correct one to me. Are both correct?

Comment: See also: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61264/die-war-sogar-mit-in-amerika https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53166/how-to-interpret-mit-in-mit-anh%c3%b6ren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sentences are equally correct and convey the same meaning.